# How do I add a "Smooth Scrolling" feature to my page's buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I am trying to create a smooth scrolling effect on the buttons of [my Codepen](https://codepen.io/c0nnexi0n/pen/YQoMMO) using the Javascript from [this example page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/) and it still "snaps" to the section of the page instead of smoothly scrolling to the section.

What is causing this to not work? (Tried adding the breaks to see if I was just going crazy because of the speed of the scroll.)

Code Below:

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="topBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="header-row">
  <div class="header-left">
    <h4>A Self-Taught Programmer's Adventure</h4>
    <h3>Victor Rojas</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="header-center">
    <img class="logo-main" src="https://victoryroads.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/cropped-artboard-1.png" title="Victory Roads">
  </div>
  <div class="header-right">
    <h4 class="text-social">Connect with me:</h4>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/spikefrs/" class="fa fa-facebook" target="_blank">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/spikefrs/"  class="fa fa-instagram">
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/victorvanrojas/" class="fa fa-linkedin">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="header-right-nav" id="topnav">
    <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#accomplishments">Accomplishments</a>
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="main-body">
  <p class="header-title" id="accomplishments">Accomplishments</p>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <p class="subheader-title">Projects</p>
      <ul>
        <p class="project"><a class ="link" href="https://codepen.io/c0nnexi0n/full/oGrowR/">Tribute Page</a></p><br>
        <p class="project"><a class ="link" href="https://victoryroads.club/">Personal Blog</a></p>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p class="subheader-title">Certificates</p>
        <ul>
          <p class="project"><a class ="link" href="https://www.coursera.org/account/accomplishments/certificate/8FGMKKQ5VN">Python Certification</a></p><br>
          <p class="project"><a class ="link" href="https://www.udemy.com/certificate/UC-MVB4P9MJ/">Marketo Certification</a></p>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <p class="header-title" id="portfolio">My Portfolio</p>
    <img class="port1" src="https://i.imgur.com/6aLPprT.png"></img>
    <img class="port2" src="https://i.imgur.com/A8tOXw3.png"></img>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
$black: #000;
$grey: #868686;
$white: #FFF;
$red: #dd4b4b;



.header-row{
  position: relative;
  background-color: $grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 40px;
}

.header-left{
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
}
.header-center{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  top: -70px;

}

.header-right{
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
  top: -145px;
}

.text-social{
  position: relative;
  left: -125px;
  top: 30px;
  text-decoration: underline;

}

.fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: right;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: $black;
}

.fa:hover{
  opacity: 20%;
  color: $red;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 2px 3px $black;
}


.header-title{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: $white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
               0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
               0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.subheader-title{
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  color: $white;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4),
               0px 8px 13px rgba(0,0,0,0.1),
               0px 18px 23px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.logo-main{
  height: 60px;
  top: -200px;
}

.header-right-nav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.header-right-nav a {
    float: right;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: arial, san-serif;
}

.header-right-nav a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

.header-right-nav a.active {
    background-color: $red;
    color: white;
}

.main-body {
    position: relative;
    background-color: $grey;
    color: $black;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.column {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: $red;
    height: 20vh;
    column-count: 1;        
    column-gap: 2em;
    left: 15px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.project {
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.link {
    color: $white;

}

.link:hover {
    color: $black;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.port1{
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 28px;
}

.port2{
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 600px;
}

#topBtn {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: red;
    color: white; 
    cursor: pointer; 
    padding: 15px; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
}

#topBtn:hover {
    background-color: #555;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.fontSize = "80px";

document.getElementsByTagName("h3")[0].style.fontSize = "25px";

document.getElementsByTagName("h4")[0].style.fontSize = "15px";

$('a[href*="#"]')
  // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
  .not('[href="#"]')
  .not('[href="#0"]')
  .click(function(event) {
    // On-page links
    if (
      location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
      && 
      location.hostname == this.hostname
    ) {
      // Figure out element to scroll to
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      // Does a scroll target exist?
      if (target.length) {
        // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000, function() {
          // Callback after animation
          // Must change focus!
          var $target = $(target);
          $target.focus();
          if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
            return false;
          } else {
            $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
            $target.focus(); // Set focus again
          };
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: `$(this).click(...` <-- you're not attaching the click event handler to the buttons.

Comment: You have a mix of jQuery, DOM, and HTML attributes for affecting your page. You should probably pick a pattern and stick with it. In other words, move `topFunction` into an event handler for that button, use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change the font sizes, etc. Also, in the code you've put here on SO, you've not included jQuery, so you're likely getting errors in your console.

Comment: Edited to match example*

@Archer I am seeing no change when it comes to [his codepen](https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dpBMVP) - am I still in the wrong here?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan topFunction was a button I tried to implement at the beginning of my project. I removed that to help focus on my navagation bar issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone. My mistake was that I did not add the [script](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js) into my program.

Comment: I also removed the Javascript elements that were changing the font size of h1, h3, and h4. Those have been added as CSS.